# Unit test Angular 2 error: Bootstrap at least one component before injecting Router?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am writing test for component in angular 2 and I see a problem as below:

[image]

Any help, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [`RouterTestingModule`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/testing/index/RouterTestingModule-class.html) instead of the `RouterModule` when testing. If you only need the directives, you can just import it as is

```
imports: [ RouterTestingModule ]
```

If you want to configure routes than you can call `withRoutes`

```
imports: [ RouterTestingModule.withRoutes(ROUTES) ]
```